# Call functions android

Tags: android

I have an onCreate function and except that I have two other functions with the names of function a() and b(). I wanna call functions like this: function a(), b(), b(), a() and after that I want to finish the activity. The problem is that I cannot call function b() from function a(). Because in that way, I need to call function b() and then a() again from function b() and this doesn't work. Is there any efficient way to call functions as I mentioned ?

Comment: `c() { a(); b(); b(); a(); finish(); }` ?

Comment: Functions!! we have methods in java not functions..

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Override
 public onCreate()
 {
     a(); b(); b(); a();
     finish();
 }
```

but this just looks too easy to be relevant, care to elaborate more on your issue?

Comment: Also if you use finish exactly after you call your function it will finish everything.

Comment: For a() it should execute a test without sound. For b() it should execute a test with sound. But when I use it in this way, I hear a sound for first round of my test and it doenst work as it should work and i dont know why. But when I call a() in onCreate and b() in a(), it works. But I need 4 rounds.

Comment: I think it's about time you edit your first post, state your intentions or PROBLEM and post your source CODE.

Answer (score 0):

First of all. Learn how to name your methods:  https://sites.google.com/site/yacoset/Home/naming-tips

2nd. post your code, so it is visible.

3rd:

```
public void onCreate(bundledInstance){
super.onCreate(bundledInstance);
a();
b();
b();
a();
}
```

will do the job for you.

Comment: In my actual code they are called something else. I used this way But it didnt work for me I don't know why. That class is not a small class and thats why I cannot copy it here. Thanks anyway.